# Can we parse an Xml file in android without using any Parsers or Api?

Tags: android

I have been using `sax` and `Dom parsers` to parse an `Xml` file in `android`.But can we parse any `xml` file without using any `parsers` or any `Api`.If yes will somebody provide me with some links to do so.

Comment: You can also use your bare hands to hit nails into wood. But what is the point?

Comment: why do you want to do that? you can code your on parser if you don't want to use the existing parser's?..

Comment: If you want to get some specific tag values inside a complex xml, you can just use string methods, or regular expressions obviously. But the existing libraries may provide much better options without any doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having troubles with traditional parsing methods, you can try a framework that does the mapping from XML to Object for you like [Simple xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)